# Css on IE7 div position incorrect

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

[image]

> Please see the picture above.  I try my best to let [div1] in the
> bottom of [div2] in IE7. but faild.Please help Me.
> Please see the picture above.  I try my best to let [div1] in the
> bottom of [div2] in IE7. but faild.Please help Me.
> Please see the picture above.  I try my best to let [div1] in the
> bottom of [div2] in IE7. but faild.Please help Me.

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;overflow: hidden;font-size:12px;">
    <div style="float:left">
        <img style="width: 30px;height: 30px;border-radius: 100%;vertical-align: middle;" src="http://cdn.5u55.cn/face/u0.jpg"> 
        <div style="margin-top:2px;font-size:9px;">name1</div>
    </div>
    <strong style="float: left; border-style: solid; border-width: 10px; border-color: #fff #d4edf4 #fff #fff; height: 0; font-size: 0; width: 0;margin-top:7px;"></strong>
    <div>
    <div style="float:left;display: inline-block;background-color: #d4edf4;position: relative;padding: 10px;line-height: 18px;border-radius: 4px;color: #333;">
         test test test test test test
    </div>
    <br clear="all" /> 
    <div style="float:left;margin-left:60px;color: #ccc;font-size:9px;">2016-02-17 22:21:00</div>
</div>
<br clear="all" /> 
<br clear="all" /> 
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;overflow: hidden;font-size:12px;">
    <div style="float:right;display: flex;-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;-webkit-box-direction: normal;flex-direction: row;-webkit-box-pack: end;justify-content: flex-end;padding: 5px;">
        <img style="width: 30px;height: 30px;border-radius: 100%;vertical-align: middle;" alt="" src="http://cdn.5u55.cn/face/u0.jpg">
        <div style="margin-top:2px;font-size:9px;">name2</div>
    </div>
    <strong style="float: right; border-style: solid; border-width: 10px; border-color: #fff  #fff #fff #f1ddde ; height: 0; font-size: 0; width: 0;margin-top:10px;margin-left:-1px;"></strong>
    <div style="float:right;background-color: #f1ddde;position: relative;padding: 10px;line-height: 18px;margin-left:42px;color: #333;">
       dadasd
    </div>
    <br clear="all" /> 
    <div style="float:right;color: #ccc;font-size:9px;margin-right:58px;">2016-02-17 22:21:00</div>
</div>
<br clear="all" /> 
<br clear="all" /> 
<div style="text-align: center;width: 100%;margin: 5px auto;font-size: 10px;margin:0 20px 10px;">
    <p style="color:red;background-color: lightGrey;padding: 5px 10px;border-radius: 5px;">thanks</p>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 10 and below is dead, IE user base is too low ([2015 December 6,3%](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp)) and [IE 10 and below is only 1,4%](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp). You should stop fool-proofing code for stone-age people. By the way using inline CSS isn't a good practice and You should avoid that.

Comment: i know that.but the question html is worked in winform webbrower.i have to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to make an css for IE only 
make a new stylesheet and link to it like this

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Now you have en stylesheet that only will have effect on IE browsers

But as said above. below IE 10 is dead, dont style for that. And avoid inline styling. for your own good.

Comment: the question html is worked in winform webbrower and how  to solve it.